# Clear description of NSArray isEqual method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

It is unclear to me how  NSArray's isEqual method compares elements of the two arrays. Does it check if both arrays contain identical objects (eg. ==) ? or does it compare the contents of both arrays using isEqual on the objects?

I find Apple's docs for this method terse and unclear. I can't find the source for NSArray.m either.

Comment: You're right that the documentation for NSObject isEqual is unclear at best, and the documentation for isEqualToArray says nothing about whether it's equivalent to isEqual.

Comment: (However, reading between the lines I'm about 95% confident that NSArray isEqual simply invokes isEqualToArray, and the latter cascades the compares appropriately.)

Comment: This may be useful if you really want the source... [link](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/CFArray.c)

Comment: Cocoa's source isn't open. You can, however, put some objects of a particular class into an array and set a breakpoint on that class's `isEqual:` to see if it gets hit when `isEqual:` is sent to the array.

Answer (score 7):

No answer exists in the modern Cocoa documentation, but if you go [all the way back to WebObjects 3.5's NSArray documentation](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.5/Reference/Frameworks/ObjC/Foundation/Classes/NSArrayClassCluster/Description.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/isEqual:), you find this gem:

> - (BOOL)`isEqual:`(id)anObject
>
> Returns YES if the receiver and anObject are equal; otherwise returns NO. A YES return value indicates that the receiver and anObject are both instances of classes that inherit from NSArray and that they both contain the same objects (as determined by the `isEqualToArray:` method).

The closest thing to an answer outside of the legacy docs is [this discussion of object comparison](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/FrameworkImpl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001286-1007347) in the Coding Guidelines for Cocoa, which seems to imply that `isEqual:` and `isEqualToWhatever:` should do the same thing, with the only difference being the level of type safety.

Still, I recommend [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to ask for the docs to be clarified.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/isEqualToArray%3a) is clear:

> Two arrays have equal contents if they each hold the same number of objects and objects at a given index in each array satisfy the isEqual: test.

That means that `isEqual` (and not `==`) wil be used to test objects for equality.

Comment: The documentation is quite unclear.  I've spent several minutes looking and cannot find any documentation on NSArray isEqual, while the documentation for NSObject isEquaL is silent on how it treats an NSArray (other than to tell you to look at the NSArray documentation).

Comment: You're quoting the docs for `isEqualToArray:`, not `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 2):

All objects in Cocoa are compared with `-isEqual:` by default. The default version of `-isEqual:` on `NSObject`, however, does a pointer comparison. So, if the object hasn't properly implemented its `-isEqual:` and `-hash` methods, it's going to simply compare pointers.

Comment: @HotLicks I disagree. Objects in Cocoa are compared with the `-isEqual:` method, period, never just `==`. I think the documentation is clear, since the container objects have specific `-isEqualTo..:` type methods that specify exactly how the comparison is made. If you simply call `-isEqual:` on these containers, they're just going to check if the objects are the same class and then call the appropriate comparison method.

Comment: The spec *does not* (anywhere that I can find) spell out how `isEqual` is applied to NSArrays.  That's the OP's complaint.

Answer (score 1):

MAYBE its kinda like this!? (typed here so there're likely typos)

```
if(![array1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || ![array2 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
 return NO;

if(array1 == array2)
 return YES;

if(array1.count != array2.count)
 return NO;

for(int i =0; i<array1.count;i++)
 if(![array1[i] isEqual:array[i]])
  return NO;

return YES;
```

Comment: That's what I'd expect. I'm hoping someone can confirm for sure.